# All events are displaying in the top left corner (Jquery Full Calender)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

So I am wondering what would cause it so that all events for the full jquery calender would display in the top left hand corner. even if there is one it will show in the tab where you have "sunday" when it might be scheduled for next monday

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a jsfiddle?

Comment: maybe absolutely positioned but you'll have to post some code or a fiddle

Comment: This code cannot be repoducded because we are using zend framework and json. any way we can debug with out....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, but only events in the current day were doing this.

It was caused by a CSS conflict - I had a rule in a custom jQuery UI CSS file that was causing the events to obey position: relative, when fullCalendar depends on events having position: absolute.

My first suggestion is to try setting the theme option to both true and false, and see if you have the same problem in both cases.

Next, try disabling any other CSS files you are using on the page, other than the default jQuery UI CSS and the fullcalendar CSS.

If you notice a change, this should give you some evidence as to where the problem is. If not... I'm not sure what to tell you :)

Answer (score 5):

My fix was as follows in my css file:

```
#calendar * {
    position: static;
}
```

Comment: While the selected answer explained the issue well, this is ultimately what fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

ithcy is right. Try disabling other css.

I also had this happen. Where all the events were at the top left corner stacked on top of each other.

I tried deactivating all other wp plugins taking off all js. None of that worked.

It ended up being css. In my css file resets I had a rule that positioned divs to be relative. I took that off and it fixed it.